# Join multiple tables based on date range selected

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have tables stored per month.  And each month contains about half a million rows.

I want to allow my application user to select any date range they choose and dynamically join the appropriate tables.  The range could be within one table or several tables.

Please suggest the best way to go about this.

Some table names:

```
sqlt_data_1_2014_01
sqlt_data_1_2014_02
sqlt_data_1_2014_03
sqlt_data_1_2014_04
sqlt_data_1_2014_05
sqlt_data_1_2014_06
...etc
```

One table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sqlt_data_1_2014_06]
(   [tagid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [intvalue] [bigint] NULL,
[floatvalue] [float] NULL,
[stringvalue] [varchar](255) NULL,
[datevalue] [datetime] NULL,
[dataintegrity] [int] NULL,
[t_stamp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([tagid] ASC, [t_stamp] ASC)
 WITH(  PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Are you confined to a specific year or can the user query multiple years?

Comment: Look into _Partitioned Views_, eg this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Multiple years too...

Comment: Use this query to find out the range of the tables you need to join `select name from sys.tables where create_date > '01/01/2014' and create_date < '06/01/2014' and name like '%sqlt_data%'`, then use the Partitioned Views as suggested by @TT.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  It looks like this will work out just fine.  Thank you TT & CJ!